# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make shells. I added everything, turned to my Ammo code to put the location of the projectile departure. There are no errors in the c# code itself, but Unity complains.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float cooldownTimer = Mathf.Infinity;
    [SerializeField] private float attackCooldown;
    [SerializeField] private Transform firePoint;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] fireballs;
    private Animator anim;
    private PlayerControllert playerMovement;
     
    private void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerMovement = GetComponent<PlayerControllert>();

    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && cooldownTimer > attackCooldown)
        {
            Attack();
        }
        cooldownTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    private void Attack()
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("attack");
        cooldownTimer = 0;

        fireballs[0].transform.position = firePoint.position;
        fireballs[0].GetComponent<Ammo>().SetDirection(Mathf.Sign(transform.localScale.x));
    }

}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ammo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    private bool hit;
    private Animator anim;
    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    private float direction;

    private void Awake()
    {
        anim.GetComponent<Animator>();
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (hit) return;
        float movementSpeed = speed * Time.deltaTime * direction;
        transform.Translate(movementSpeed, 0, 0);

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        hit = true;
        boxCollider.enabled = false;
        anim.SetTrigger("explode");
    }
    public void SetDirection(float _direction)
    {
        direction = _direction;
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        hit = false;
        boxCollider.enabled = true;

        float localScaleX = transform.localScale.x;
        if (Mathf.Sign(localScaleX) != _direction)
            localScaleX = -localScaleX;

        transform.localScale = new Vector3(localScaleX, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }
    private void Deactivate()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

[Ammo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnTOE.png)
[Player Attack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcOOg.png)
I repeated everything according to the guide. I've watched the video several times, but for some reason it still doesn't work for me

Comment: "But Unity complains" does not tell us anything. What is the specific error?

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Have you assigned gameobjects to the array fireballs in the first script?